# How to run a webpack app in production on a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, webpack

I have a react app with a custom webpack setup. For development on my environment I had it setup to work fine, but now I want to create a docker image of it and use my app in production mode. But I have no clue how to do it. I have been looking up information online and found a few tutorials like [this](https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/dockerize-your-react-app-4j2e). But they used a multistaged Dockerfile and finished it off with nginx. I am not concerned about that right now, all I want is a simple Dockerfile that will let my production code run on a container.

Ran into different problems along the way but got over them and now I am at the point where I have a Dockerfile that can create an image of my work and run successfully in a container. But now the UI wont load. At this stage I am on the verge of giving up as this is something that seems basic, but is proving next to impossible!

Can anyone shed any light on this for me and point me in the right direction?

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "production": "webpack-dev-server --mode production",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: "./src/index.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        port: "9000",
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './'), // where dev server will look for static files, not compiled
        publicPath: '/', //relative path to output path where  devserver will look for compiled files
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // base path where to send compiled assets
        publicPath: '/' // base path where referenced files will be look for
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') // shortcut to reference src folder from anywhere
        }
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { // config for html
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            { // config for images
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'images',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            { // config for fonts
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "index.html",
            title: "Candledata"
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["css/*.*", "js/*.*", "fonts/*.*", "images/*.*"]
        }),
    ]
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . /app
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["yarn", "production"]
```

The docker image gets created, and can be ran in a container. When I go to `localhost:9000` the page wont load. The developers console doesn't show anything but the network tab says it failed to get the document;

[image: network tab]

Any ideas on how I can get this working as expected?

**Update #1**

**Docker commands**

```
docker build -t frontend .
docker run -i --rm -p 9000:9000 --network=whole_network frontend
```

**Update #2**

[image: wget]

Comment: The tutorials you've found that `RUN yarn build`, then use a second build stage `FROM nginx` are probably a better practice, and will yield a smaller, faster, and more secure final image.

Comment: You see @David Maze, I have no idea on how to configure nginx and my app does a redirect to a keycloak server on login too

Answer (score 1):

What's the cmd you used to run the container? Did you use the -p parameter like at:

```
docker run --name=myserver -p SERVERPORT:9000  .......
```

so the docker port 9000 could be seen through SERVERPORT?

The docker container basically works like an OS environment and webpack is just used to optimize js compilation:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

In the package.json you could use:

```
"build": "webpack --config=webpack.prod.config.js --progress --watch-poll -p"
```

so you can specify the webpack configuration file to compile for production.

What is the server you are using? node? Did you started the node server? Webpack compilation for production is supposed to create just "optimized js code". But you still need a server that will pick up that code and this is not necessarily the server you used during development.

### Interesting article about setting Dev and Production environments

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/creating-a-production-ready-webpack-4-config-from-scratch/

Comment: I have updated the question to include my docker cli commands but yes, I have the -p option included

Comment: from within the container run wget localhost:9000  and see if you get the web page you want. Also, check the server firewall to see if port 9000 is opened.

Comment: I have included an image of the cli result

Comment: is the server port 9000 (not docker container port) opened for http stuff?

Comment: Also.... what is that  whole_network  value for? never used that! did you created a docker network called  whole_network ?

Comment: So looking at my code I see I have set the devServer to 9000, and nothing for prod, which (I assume) is default 80/8080. Just retrying it here now with that. 
whole_network is a custom network I have connecting multiple containers together

Comment: tried it with port 80 and getting - ReferenceError: window is not defined - when I try to start the container

Comment: depends on the port your node server is using. If your nodeserver is using 9000 in the docker container, them you could use   -p 7080:9000  to work with the port 7080 of the host.  What you get when you run  docker ps -a?

Comment: 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp

Comment: I use npm instead of yarn. I had a similar problem to yours. I had to create a separate webpack config file for production and specify some optimizations like compiling the code to ignore console.log messages. The optimized js code was called from an html web page which was placed at a server all within the same docker container. Your webpack.config does not mention any production stuff. So, my suggestion is just use another webpack.config file for production (using your dev one as base) and change a little bit every time until you get what you need.

Comment: So I seen a tutorial on that after I wrote this question and now have 3 webpack files, webpack.common, webpack.prod and webpack.dev. The thing that I just don't get is how do I get it running on a dockerfile? Even trying to run production locally I can't get it to work

Comment: what are the yarn cmds you run for dev?

Comment: If you follow how they work with the webpack and package.json then you need to do something similar for production but starting with the optimized code.